# How to search a PDF (1.4) byte array for a target string?

Tags: java, pdf

I know this is probably a bit unusual, but I'd like to find out if a PDF document (a byte array) contains a particular piece of text. I create the docs myself in Java using the iText library v2.1.7, which produces docs compliant with the PDF 1.4 spec.

My initial naive attempt was something like this:

```
byte[] target = "the target text".getBytes("UTF-8");
int index = Bytes.indexOf(pdfBytes, target); // Guava lib
System.out.println( index ); // always -1 (not found)
```

I just don't understand enough about how these types of documents are encoded to figure out what I need to do. I suppose what I really need to find out is what kind of encoding I need to use on the target text when I'm converting to bytes, so that it will match what the PDF uses.

I created a small sample PDF document which contains nothing except a phrase with the words `one two three four five`. This is what the contents of that PDF file look like if I `cat` the file in a Linux terminal (or use `vim` to view it):

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
2 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 71>>stream
x�+�r
�24U�02I�2P0Q�n�
�F
!i\�y�
%��
%E��
i��E
i�e��!Y0Ů!\�\���
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Contents 2 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]/Font<</F1 1 0 R>>>>/Parent 3 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Subtype/Type1/Type/Font/BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Kids[4 0 R]/Type/Pages/Count 1/ITXT(2.1.7)>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 3 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</ModDate(D:20171216101023Z)/CreationDate(D:20171216101023Z)/Producer(iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT)>>
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000309 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000397 00000 n 
0000000152 00000 n 
0000000460 00000 n 
0000000505 00000 n 
trailer
<</Info 6 0 R/ID [<9e1d205d229e3d1b5b56354a7da26844><7bf1bdf9e8d048c5795c7785954d9360>]/Root 5 0 R/Size 7>>
startxref
615
%%EOF
```

Some of those character encodings have not translated properly in the copy-and-paste, so if you copy and save what you see there, you'll get a corrupt PDF. [Here's a link](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/rtf-misc/test.pdf) to a copy of that PDF.

I've tried encoding my target string to various encodings such as CP-1252 and WinAnsiEncoding, but these are unrecognized character sets.

---

I didn't think this would cause me much trouble initially, but I haven't yet been able to figure out how to do this. I do have a workaround that gets me the same result, but it's a solution that's specifically intended for the iText library i.e. not a general solution for searching text in a PDF byte array.

If I use iText to parse the byte array that I want to search, I can iterate over each page of the PDF and extract the text:

```
private static boolean doesPDFContain(byte[] pdf, String text) throws Exception {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
    int numPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfTextExtractor extractor = new PdfTextExtractor(reader);

    for (int i=1; i<=numPages; i++) {
        if ( extractor.getTextFromPage(i).contains(text) ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'd still be interested in hearing if it's possible to do what I was originally attempting.

Comment: this book may help : [link](https://www.google.dz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjs6c_nvo7YAhXHbhQKHaJHBbMQFghRMAY&url=https%3A%2F%2Freadthedocs.org%2Fprojects%2Funicodebook%2Fdownloads%2Fpdf%2Flatest%2F&usg=AOvVaw1VOE2uFLNIHSHf8N2nh4X0) ,read the definition first then look under Java title page 51 . , also try to find out about `IBM852` charset . also this converting method may help : [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/ISO88592akaLatin2.htm) , good luck .

Comment: Your naive attempt fails because – as can be seen in your PDF dump – text is usually compressed. I have no idea what the comment above suggests: the encoding of the only font in the file is WinAnsi. PDF does not support UTF8 at all! It may be the naive getTextFromPage fails because the text is scattered. Print out what it returns and check, and try with the different extraction strategies.

Comment: Just to be clear, the `getTextFromPage` approach I mention in the edit is working fine. It solves my problem e.g. find some text in a PDF. You mention that PDF text is compressed. So, presumably I'd have to find out what compression algorithm is being used (possibly LZW or Flate) and decompress. But, it's only parts of the PDF content that's compressed? I wonder how you'd get around that...

Comment: What is the question then? Yes, it is "a solution that's specifically intended for the iText library". The alternative is to write the entire functionality from scratch. For that, read the PDF specifications. All of the details you ask for are in there. Absolutely doable; it is exactly what I did and how I got around that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why your naive approach --- simply looking for the text in a specific encoding --- in general won't work.

The text you are looking for, text displayed on screen, is drawn by text drawing instructions in some content stream. (Let's ignore the cases of graphics looking like text but being drawn using vector or bitmap graphics commands and of missing or inaccurate font encoding information.)

- The text you are looking for is not necessarily drawn by a single instruction. The text "Hello", for example, might be written using two consecutive commands:

  ```
  (Hel) Tj (lo) Tj
  ```

  The different commands need not even follow each other in the content stream, they may be spread across it.
- Each font in PDFs can use a different encoding for its strings, and these encodings don't even need to be standard encodings, they may be ad-hoc encodings created on the fly by the PDF creator program.
- The content stream can (and usually does) require a filter for decoding, e.g. in the PDF above the content stream in the object 2 requires **FlateDecode** filtering (essentially: unzipping).
- The PDF may be encrypted (in which case more specifically strings and streams are encrypted); even PDFs you can open without any further ado in your PDF viewer may be encrypted using a default password (this technique is used for encoding permissions).

Thus, to inspect the contents of content streams, you may have to

- decrypt the file; then
- decode the content streams with their respectively applicable filters; then
- parse the content stream instructions to know for each text drawing instruction

  - which font is used to draw the text and
  - at which position the text is drawn; then
- decode the string contents according to the information in the font; then
- sort the text pieces according to the position information and put them together as a single string.

In this character string you can eventually search the text in a naive way.

Comment: Jaysus, no way I'm going to all that trouble. I'll stick with with re-parsing the PDF using iText. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @mkl: Detailed answer but one correction: Streams *cannot* be embedded into object streams, only plain indirect objects.

Comment: @gettalong thanx. You're right of course. I corrected the answer.