# GSON / iText: Extract Text From PDF 1.7 byte[]

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, gson, itext

I'm automating tests using Rest-Assured and GSON - and need to validate the contents of a PDF file that is returned in the response of a POST request. The content of the files vary and can contain anything from just text, to text and tables, or text and tables and graphics.  Every page can, and most likely will be different as far a glyph content. I am only concerned with ALL text on the pdf page - be it just plain text, or text inside of a table, or text associated with (or is inside of) an image. Since all pdf's returned by the request are different, I cannot define search areas (as far as I know).  I just need to extract all text on the page.

I extract the pdf data into a byte array like so:

```
        Gson pdfGson = new Gson();
        byte[] pdfBytes =
            pdfGson.fromJson(this.response.as(JsonObject.class)
                    .get("pdfData").getAsJsonObject().get("data").getAsJsonArray(), byte[].class);
```

(I've tried other extraction methods for the byte[], but this is the only way I've found that returns valid data.) This returns a very large byte[] like so:

```
[37, 91, 22, 45, 23, ...]
```

When I parse the array I run into the same issue as [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845441/how-to-search-a-pdf-1-4-byte-array-for-a-target-string) (except my pdf is 1.7) and I attempt to implement the accepted answer, adjusted for my purposes and as explained in the documentation for iText:

```
    byte[] decodedPdfBytes = PdfReader.decodeBytes(pdfBytes, new PdfDictionary(), FilterHandlers.getDefaultFilterHandlers());

    IRandomAccessSource source = new RandomAccessSourceFactory().createSource(decodedPdfBytes);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ReaderProperties readerProperties = new ReaderProperties();
    
    // Ineffective:
    readerProperties.setPassword(user.password.getBytes());
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(source, readerProperties);
    // Ineffective:
    pdfReader.setUnethicalReading(true);

    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, new PdfWriter(baos));

    for(int i = 1; i < pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        String text = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfDoc.getPage(i));
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

This DOES decode the pdf page, and return text, but it is only the header text.  No other text is returned.

For what it's worth, on the front end, when the user clicks the button to generate the pdf, it returns a blob containing the download data, so I'm relatively sure that the metadata is GSA encoded, but I'm not sure if that matters at all.  I'm not able to share an example of the pdf docs due to sensitive material.

Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!  I've spent 3 days trying to find a solution.

Comment: *"This DOES decode the pdf page, and return text, but it is only the header text. No other text is returned."* - Thus, this apparently is not a question of how you retrieve the file (because apparently it is a valid PDF, otherwise you would not have got so far); instead it very likely is an issue of the PDF itself. Either there is only the header text drawn as text (everything else, if there at all, drawn as bitmap or vector graphics but not as text) or the body text is drawn using a font not providing the required information for text extraction. For more please share the PDF in question.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up @mkl - I'm not sure how to handle this because sharing the pdf would actually violate a confidentiality agreement and possibly a few privacy laws... I can post a screenshot with everything blacked out, but I'm not sure how helpful that would be.

Comment: Unfortunately a screenshot would not provide the required information. Do you happen to have a support contract with iText Software? The support team handles all documents with the highest confidentiality and they are automatically deleted 30 days after an issue is closed, and if you want, you can even get an explicit Non Disclosure Agreement with iText Software, even though non disclosure is already part of the standard support terms.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @AmedeeVanGasse!  I'll have to look into that.  I tried to create a generic pdf version to share but unfortunately there would be nothing left after redactions.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a solution - ultimately we wound up going a different route.  We never found a solution to this specific issue.